# Strongly-typed reference from input tag-helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0, strong-typing, tag-helpers

## Context

Here's an instance of a `form` tag helper from one of the ASP.NET Core documentation example projects:

```html
<form asp-page="./Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Find by name: 
            <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" /> |
            <a asp-page="./Index">Back to full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Link](https://github.com/dharmatech/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/0b70dd128fd79e92238dbede0092be22687f4e13/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu50/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml#L14-L23) to the lines on github.

In that `form` code, the following line:

```html
<input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
```

references `SearchString` which corresponds to the `searchString` parameter in the `OnGetAsync` method:

```cs
public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageIndex)
{
    ...
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/dharmatech/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/0b70dd128fd79e92238dbede0092be22687f4e13/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu50/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs#L31-L74) to the lines on github.

## The Issue

In the line mentioned above:

```html
<input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
```

the reference to `SearchString` is not strongly-typed. So for example, if there's a typo in the reference:

```html
<input type="text" name="SearchStringAbc" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
```

the program will still compile and run, but the program will not work as expected.

## One approach

Here's one approach I took to make this reference strongly-typed.

Add the following properties to the `IndexModel` page model:

```cs
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string sortOrder { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string currentFilter { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string searchString { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int? pageIndex { get; set; }
```

[Link](https://github.com/dharmatech/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/1ed40cdfa2e5159cde482cbd93b67a6617a96ab2/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu50/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs#L25-L35)

Remove the parameters from `OnGetAsync` (we'll use the above properties instead):

```cs
public async Task OnGetAsync()
```

[Link](https://github.com/dharmatech/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/1ed40cdfa2e5159cde482cbd93b67a6617a96ab2/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu50/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs#L44)

Use the `input` tag helper with a strongly-typed reference to the `searchString` property:

```html
<input asp-for="searchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
```

[Link](https://github.com/dharmatech/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/1ed40cdfa2e5159cde482cbd93b67a6617a96ab2/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu50/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml#L18)

This works great; if there's a typo in the reference to `searchString` we get red squigglies:

[image]

## The Question

Is the above approach the recommended way to making this reference strongly-typed?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, the use of strong typing has the help of IntelliSense, compile-time error checking can also eliminate the need to convert between types and other advantages. What you do is currently more general, and it is recommended to use it.